# How to pass command line argument to python script from docker run command?

Tags: python, docker

I have created a docker file. i can build an image and run it. next i want to pass command line arugument when i run a docker container. i am planning to read those arguments in my python , app.py file and make decisions based on that. How to pass command line argument from docker run command?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

ADD app.py /

RUN pip install pandas

CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

app.py

```
import sys

//read argument from command line 
print(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `docker run` the container, you can supply a command at the end of it.  This replaces the Dockerfile's `CMD`, so you need to repeat the script name, but any arguments there will be passed through as-is.

If the script begins with `#!/usr/bin/env python` as its very very first line, and it's executable `chmod +x app.py`, then you don't need to repeat the `python` interpreter; these examples will assume you've done that.

```bash
docker run --rm your-image \
  ./app.py first-argument
```

It's also possible to use a Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` here.  This isn't my preferred use of `ENTRYPOINT` -- it makes some kinds of debugging a little bit harder, and there is a different pattern for it I prefer -- but it is common enough to be [included in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint).  The basic setup here is that [the `CMD` is passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) so you can set the `ENTRYPOINT` to the actual command and the `CMD` to its arguments.

```bash
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./ ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./app.py"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD []                  # must be JSON-array syntax, could include defaults
```

In this setup both the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` *must* use JSON-array "exec" syntax (shell-form `ENTRYPOINT` won't allow `CMD` arguments; shell-form `CMD` makes `sh -c` visible as arguments to your program) but that means you can't use shell features like environment-variable expansion as part of the command (the program can still use `os.environ` as normal).

The `docker run` option only overrides the `CMD`, and so only supplies the program's arguments

```bash
docker run --rm your-image \
  first-argument
```

But some kinds of routine debugging need an awkward `docker run --entrypoint` option to not run the script.

```bash
# run an interactive shell instead of the program
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash your-image
# without ENTRYPOINT: `docker run --rm -it your-image bash`

# double-check the file listing and permissions
docker run -it --entrypoint ls your-image -l /app
# without ENTRYPOINT: `docker run --rm your-image ls -l /app
```